# Combobox Selection Changed event in silverlight shows error while changing the listitem

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, combobox

I am creating a combobox event while changing the selection changed is done. My code is

**C#**

```
private void smscbox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (((ComboBox)sender).SelectedItem != null)
    {
        ComboBoxItem cbi = (ComboBoxItem)((ComboBox)sender).SelectedItem;
        if (cbi.Content.ToString() == "Selected Class")
        {
            selectedclass.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            dgstudentsms.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
        else
        {
            selectedclass.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            dgstudentsms.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }
}
```

and in **XAML**

```
<ComboBox Name="sendsmscbox" SelectionChanged="smscbox_SelectionChanged" >
    <ListBoxItem Content="All Students"/>
    <ListBoxItem Content="Selected Students"/>
</ComboBox>
```

I am getting a window as shown below

[image]

can any one help me with this!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to cast a `ListBoxItem` to a `ComboBoxItem`.

Use `ComboBoxItem` in your XAML markup instead of `ListBoxItem`.

```
<ComboBox Name="sendsmscbox" SelectionChanged="smscbox_SelectionChanged" >
    <ComboBoxItem Content="All Students"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Selected Students"/>
</ComboBox>
```

Or if you really meant to use a `ListBoxItem` in your XAML *(probably not)*, then cast to the correct type in your code-behind:

```
ListBoxItem lbi = (ListBoxItem)((ComboBox)sender).SelectedItem;
```

Comment: Why they have a difference in windows and Silverlight?

Comment: Thank you, Now I am aware of it